# react router navigate links from rest api

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new in react and faced with the problem when tried to accomplish navigate through my api pages. What I've done: http://pastebin.com/hxf9PJ8k
It works perfectly on my opinion, but show only first api page. Links to all user profile works too, it was simple to do just adding an  id to api link. So, my api returned to me objects that is actually users, and overall count of users in database and links to next page if exist or null and previous page or null. Now I cannot understand how to use those link to create 2 buttons — next and prev. How to pass whole link or just part next to `page=` to Users props and make xhr request. 
Api example view:

`count:  2302
next:   "http://localhost:8080/instant/api/?page=2"
previous:

results:

    0:  Object
    1:  Object
    2:  Object`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what suggest to yo to do is to create a **currentPage** variable which makes your logic very simple.

for **previous** and **next** buttons create a separate component to handle paging condition, handle any click event on the parent component to keep it simple.

```
class PrevBtn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.props.clickHandler = this.props.clickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        let button = null;
        const {currentPage} = this.props;

        if(currentPage>1){
          button = <a onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>Prev</a>
        }else{
          button = <a disabled="disabled">Prev</a>
        }
        return(<div>{button}</div>)
      }
    }
```

I just did an example for you in [codePen](http://codepen.io/pedrommuller/pen/BWmbmZ/), but I just did the prev button logic, you can figure it out how to do the **next** button component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a really newbee in react and I don't grasp how I pass state of next and previous vars of Users component to those childes component. Problem is that I cannot use links that comes from api. For example, link to the next page is domain/api/?page=2 — how can I take this link and pass it to Users instead of current link and reload Users component with new data from api? Sorry for my blurry explanation.

Comment: I'd suggest not to pass previous and next var, instead of that use a variable that handles  current Page, then calculate if previous or next are going to enable the user, based on some navigation conditions, as the example I explained earlier (if currentPage>1), every time your state change you should fetch the corresponding data from your API

Comment: Don't thin in terms of links, URLs, because that would be configured in your API client, think in terms of current page